# Emacs with KeyRemap4MacBook and rebound keys does not recognize some shortcuts (p.x. M-})

Tags: macos, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

Ok the explanation of my setup will take some time:

I'm german and using the [Neo keyboard layout](http://www.neo-layout.org/) on my mac with [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) to get the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> and <kbd>#</kbd> keys as additional modifier keys. See the following picture for the checked options.

[image: Settings for KeyRemap4MacBook]

Then I rebind the following keys in emacs

```
  (setq mac-option-key-is-meta nil)
  (setq mac-option-modifier nil)
  (setq mac-command-key-is-meta t)
  (setq mac-command-modifier 'control)
  (setq mac-control-modifier 'meta)
```

With these options I get the following when pressing for example <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Capslock</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> in emacs which should be the same as <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd>:

[image: Error message]

Sadly I cannot bind this key combination. Any Idea why this happens and how I can circumvent it without changing my keyboard setup significantly?

Comment: did you perform the "PCKeyboardHack" install and change the CapsLock keycode?

Comment: No I did not. I used the Mac OS X keyboard preferences to make CapsLock another Option key. (SystemPreferences->Keyboard->Modifier Keys...)

Comment: Ok this does not seem to be possible at all. http://wiki.neo-layout.org/wiki/MacOsEmacs. This guy says he cant get it to run either.